# Is the $\chi^2$ value of a $\chi^2$ test proportional to sample size?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test

In practice, I noticed that the value grows as the sample size grows. By the formulation $\frac{n(ad-bc)^2}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+d)(c+d)}$ I find that the value is supposed to be proportional to the sample size. Is that true? Or does there exist another relationship between the two?

Comment: You seem to be looking at at $2 \times 2$ table for which the chi-squared distribution has 1 degree of freedom. So the critical value for a test at 5% level is $c = 3.84$ and that does not change with sample size. (You reject at the 5% level if chi-sq stat $< c.$ // However, if $H_0$ is false the chi-sq stat will increase with larger sample size $n.$ (Equivalent so saying that the power of the test increases with $n.)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your $2 \times 2$ table is as shown below:

```
TBL = rbind(c(4,8), c(6,6));  TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    8
[2,]    6    6

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.17143, df = 1, p-value = 0.6788
```

With a very small amount of data (24 subjects altogether) the first row
seems to suggest a 1:2 ratio of counts, whereas the second row seems
to sugest a 1:1 ratio. If that's true $H_0$ is false. But the test statistic
0.17 is not large enough to reject, as seen by the P-value 0.68 > 0.5.$

However, if roughly these same proportions of counts hold up with many
more subjects (2401 below), then the chi-squared statistic will be much larger, the P-value will be much smaller, and you will soundly reject $H_0.$ Consider the following table:

```
TBL = rbind(c(401,797), c(610,593));  TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  401  797
[2,]  610  593
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 72.43, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: That is correct, I am considering the case for binary-valued random variables. Does it hold that chi-squared is proportional to sample size?